# Use emoji in typescript variable naming

Tags: typescript

When a variable name contains an emoji in my typescript file, I get error `1127 Invalid Character`. I'd like to use emojis to provide some visual cues in my source code.

Is there a good reason not to use emojis in a .ts file?

Is there an option I can use to disable to this error my `tsconfig.json` file?

```js
const myVar: string = "hello"
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.path.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "custom_typings/"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "custom_typings"
  ]
}
```

EDIT: See this article for a detailed explanation of why emojis are not allowed in js variable names (https://thekevinscott.com/emojis-in-javascript/)[https://thekevinscott.com/emojis-in-javascript/]

TSC version: 4.0.2

Comment: JavaScript doesn't allow emoji characters in variable names, and because typescript compiles down to JavaScript it makes sense for it to follow the same convention. Otherwise, the compiler would have to rename the variables to something js-compatible, while at the same time making sure the compiler variable name doesn't already exist somewhere else in the scope. This can be done, but it would make the ts-compiler slower and more complex, especially in development mode.

Comment: you should however be able to use emojis in object keys, if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript, and therefore typescript, do not support emoji identifiers.

You can use some unicode characters like `var ಠ_ಠ = 42` but emoji are not supported. There is no setting to make this work because it does not work in javascript.

Some more technical detail on this here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6

Comment: I mean technically ts could compile variable names to something else, kinda like when using a minifier. But it would add a lot of complexity for very little value

Comment: I suppose you could _add_ a compile step to do anything. But there is nothing in javascript or typescript to support this.